# How can I add a "filter" button to the filter bar in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

As a UI improvement, I'd like to put a button the filtertoolbar so that users can either press enter to filter or click the button.

This seems like quite a small thing to me, but I can't seem to work out how to do it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `triggerToolbar` method of the filter toolbar. To do this you need execute something like above code inside of your `click` event handler

```js
$("#gridid")[0].triggerToolbar();
```